# Get 5 closest elements to an element in array including that element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get 5 closest elements to given element, including that element, in array. For example, if we have:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17]
```

and I want to get 5 closest elements to `11`, it should return `[4, 7, 11, 12, 13]`. If i pass `1` it should return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]`. If I pass `15` it should return `[11, 12, 13, 15, 17]`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific programming question. _"How can I write the code"_ and _"Can somebody write the code for me"_ aren't specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant;

You might've meant a code to find the element and return the five nearest elements to it by place in the array;

Or you might've meant a code to find the 5 numbers closest to a number you say.

### IF you meant the first case

There are two ways to do so,

#### A value as a parameter

Use this code:

```js
function closestNByValue(arr, value, n) {
    let ind = arr.indexOf(value);
    let finalArr = [];
    if (n > arr.length) {
        finalArr = Array.from(arr);
    } else if (ind == -1) {
        finalArr = [];
    } else if (ind <= n/2 - 0.5) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(0, n);
    } else if (ind >= (arr.length - n/2) - 0.5) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(-n);
    } else if (n%2 == 0) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(ind-(n/2), ind+(n/2));
    } else {
        finalArr = arr.slice(ind-(n/2 - 0.5), ind+(n/2 + 0.5));
    }
    return finalArr;
}

console.log(closestNByValue([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17], 11, 5))
```

How does it do the job?

Okay first we need to find the index of the value and save it in `ind` (short form of 'index') and we check multiple different situations for what the `ind` is so we'd be able to output the best answer as `finalArr`.

There are two exceptions; what if there was no such value in our array? then `ind = -1` and we'd return an empty array; or what if the number of elements nearby that we seek is larger than or equal to the `arr.length`? then we'd return all of the `arr`.

But if there were no exceptions, there are three different situations for the `ind`; first, `ind` is a number that makes us have all of the `finalArr` values from the first of `arr`, second, `ind` be a number that makes us have all of the `finalArr` values from the last of `arr`, and third, `ind` being a number that we have to select half from the indexes smaller than `ind` and half, larger.

If it is the third way, the way we select we'd be different depending on the oddity of the numbers we want to select.

And we'll have a conditional statement for each situation and return the `finalArr`.

#### An index as a parameter

```js
function closestNByIndex(arr, ind, n) {
    let finalArr = [];
    if (n > arr.length) {
        finalArr = Array.from(arr);
    } else if (ind == -1) {
        finalArr = [];
    } else if (ind <= n/2 - 0.5) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(0, n);
    } else if (ind >= (arr.length - n/2) - 0.5) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(-n);
    } else if (n%2 == 0) {
        finalArr = arr.slice(ind-(n/2), ind+(n/2));
    } else {
        finalArr = arr.slice(ind-(n/2 - 0.5), ind+(n/2 + 0.5));
    }
    return finalArr;
}
console.log(closestNByIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17], 5, 5))
```

Similar to the first code it works, though we have the index and we don't search for it.

The point is, if you use the function with value, it'd do the nearest 5 elements of the first value that equals the entry but such confusion is not being tolerated in the second code.

### IF you meant the second case

This is a code I coded:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17];

function allDiff(arr, num1, num2) {
  const finalArr = [];
  const x = Math.abs(num2 - num1);
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
    if (Math.abs(arr[y] - num1) == x) {
      finalArr.push(arr[y]);
    }
  }
  return finalArr;
}

function deleteArr(arr, delet) {
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (delet.includes(arr[x])) {
      delete arr[x];
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function closest(arr, num) {
  const map = new Map()
  arr2 = Array.from(arr);
  let key, value;
  for (let x = 0; x < arr2.length; x++) {
    key = Math.abs(arr2[x] - num);
    value = allDiff(arr2, num, arr2[x]);
    arr2 = deleteArr(arr2, value);
    map.set(key, value);
  }
  return map;
}

function closestN(arr, num, n) {
  const map = closest(arr, num);
  const mapKeys = Array.from(map.keys());
  const mapKeysSorted = mapKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  let finalArr = [];
  let y;
  for (let i = 0; i < mapKeysSorted.length; i++) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      break;
    }
    y = map.get(mapKeysSorted[i]);
    if (n < y.length) {
      finalArr = finalArr.concat(y.slice(0, n + 1));
      break;
    }
    finalArr = finalArr.concat(y);
    n -= y.length;
  }
  return finalArr;
}
console.log(closestN(arr, 11, 5));
```

It might be a little too long, but I have programmed it as you can give it any array (arr) with integer values, an integer (num) that you'd like it to be the base and another integer (n) for the number of the size of the output array, 5 in this case.

#### Explaining the code

The function `closest` would return a map of (*the difference between the numbers*, *a list of the numbers in the *`arr`* that differs the number equal to their key*).

The main function, `closestN`, calls the `closest` function and saves the map in the `map` variable.

Then it sorts the keys of the map in `mapKeysSorted`.

Now, a for loop loops through the `mapKeySorted` array and pushes new elements to the `finalArr` until the size of the `finalArr` reaches the number of elements we seek.

The main function is the *closestN*.

Comment: Your codes are too long. I prefer clean and short codes.

Comment: Yes, @debugger! It's because I misunderstood the question first and sought a code that searched for the nearest "numbers" not "indexes". But I have added two short codes for what now I understood they sought.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get to your goal:

1. To start, first thing to do is finding the `index` of the wanted number in the array. Example index of `1` in your array `arr` is `0`. The index will help in extracting the numbers later on. The method [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will help us in finding the index.
2. Then, we need to find the position at which will start extaracting the closest numbers (in terms of position **not** value). As seen from the desired output you have provided, usually you want the returned array to be in the following structure:

```
output: [
  2 nearest numbers (from N left), 
  the wanted number,
  2 nearest numbers (from N right)
]
```

This can get tricky so we should make sure to deal with some edge case like when the wanted element is sitting at position `0`.

3. Extract the numbers and return them as an array as described by your desired output. The use of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method will come in handy here which allow us to extract the numbers just as we need.

Here's a live demo demonstrating solution:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17],
  /** a function that returns an array containing the "5" (depending on "arr" length that could be less) nearest numbers (in terms of position) in "arr" array to the supplied number "n" */
  findClosestNumbers = n => {
    /** make sure we don't exceed the array length */
    const toTake = 5 > arr.length ? arr.length : 5,
      /** find the index of the wanted nulber "n", if "-1" is returned then "n" cannot be found ion the array "arr" */
      idx = arr.findIndex(el => n == el),
      /** 
       * from where we should start returning the nearest numbers (the position of the first number to extract from "arr" 
       * the below condition help deal with some edge cases like when "n" is the last element in "arr" 
       */
      startIdx = idx + toTake / 2 > arr.length ?
      arr.length - 5 :
      (idx - 2 >= 0 ?
        idx - 2 :
        0);
    /** return the nearest numbers or return an empty array "[]" if the number "n" is not found on the array "arr" */
    return idx == -1 ? [] : arr.slice(startIdx, startIdx + 5);
  };

/** run for various scenarios */
console.log('For 1 =>', findClosestNumbers(1));
console.log('For 11 =>', findClosestNumbers(11));
console.log('For 15 =>', findClosestNumbers(15));
console.log('For 17 =>', findClosestNumbers(17));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

> The demo above is meant to help you understand how things could work and it is not the only way to get to your goal. Also, because I kept it as simple as possible, the above demo is wide open for improvements.